# Sapper export not recognising file

Tags: export, svelte, sapper, npx

Trying to export my sapper project into the folder 'hostingsolutions'. Works fine except for any page which isn't index.svelte. This problem only occurs whenever I try to set the basepath of 'hostingsolutions'. When left as the default it works fine.

```
polka() // You can also use Express
    .use(
        'hostingsolutions'
        compression({ threshold: 0 }),
        sirv('static', { dev }),
        sapper.middleware()
    )
    .listen(PORT, err => {
        if (err) console.log('error', err);
    });
```

```
npx sapper export --basepath hostingsolutions``
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDG2C.png)

Comment: There is a comma missing after 'hostingsolutions'.  Is that in you code or just a copy and paste error on this post?

Comment: @digby280 Oh yeah sorry, that's just an issue with the post. Has a comma in the original.

Comment: Works for me if I make the changes above to the standard sapper template.  Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?